# Ruby on rails: What kind of object should I use when it doesn't represent the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

There is something I don't really get with ruby-on-rails (I'm very new to it). 
If my understanding is correct we use the model objects in the views.

The model object is the exact representation of the database. But in a lot of cases what we want to show in the view isn't the exact representation of the database.

Let's say we have an object line in the database:

```
line [line_id, quantity, category_id]
```

So if I want to show a list of lines there is no problem I can use the model object "line". But what if I want to show one line by category with a sum of the quantity for that category ?

Should I use the line object ? I feel bad about that because each line will not reflect a line in the database.
Should I create another kind of object ? Some sort of ViewModel that doesn't exist in the database but is usefull for rendering.

I'm not sure this is very clear... Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always displaying data exactly as it is in the database happens only in tutorials :)

In real-world apps it is often necessary to transform data before presenting. This has many names: ViewModel (as you mentioned), Decorator, Presenter and others. So yes, make new objects for this, there's no reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for this very quick answer. It feel better with a confirmation. Where should I create those ViewModel kind of object. Ruby on rails looks very structured with specific folders for each kind of object (model, controller, ...) ?

Comment: @YohanBéjannin: you can create new folders. `app/view_models`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you display categories with a column in the view that shows the total quantity for each category, it would make sense to use the `Category` class in your application. This should be an ActiveRecord model.

On this model, you can define a method that reads the lines and sums the quantity. It could look like this:

```
def total_quantity
  lines.map(&:quantity).sum
end
```

This method will read your lines (assuming you have set up a `has_many :lines` relationship in the Category class. Then it will read the `quantity` method on each lines and put the result in an array. Finally it will add the values together.

Note that this approach is a starting point and not very fast for larger sets of data. The approach can be improved through either lazy loading or specialized queries.

As your application grows in size, the number of methods such as the one above may grow in size to the point where the Category class becomes hard to understand. At this point, you may want to start looking for an intuitive ways to extract these methods into separate classes.